# Import Texas House map PlanH414 into SQL server using ArcGIS online

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-online, sql-server

I would like to know if there is a way to import a specific shapefile into SQL Server 2016.

The shapefile is downloadable from https://data.capitol.texas.gov/dataset/planh414.

We have access to ArcGIS Online only.

Comment: Yes possible, but your need an ETL tool, You will need to expand your options.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can use an array of general purpose ETL tools for loading files to a SQL Server. But I don't have access to any GIS specific tools other than this ArcGIS. Can you provide any pointer to obtaining a map file from ArcGIS online?